# What makes up the wealth of my fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How can I find out what contributes to the majority of the wealth of my fortress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dwarf Fortress wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Wealth):

> **Your fortress's total Created Wealth is visible on the z - status screen once you have a bookkeeper with at least novice appraiser skill** (though your bookkeeper still needs to do quite a bit of work to achieve and maintain exact figures). **All objects with any value** (including mined-out areas, bridges, engravings and every kind of created good) **will be included in the total**. Artifacts are usually one of the largest influences of fortress wealth. Artifacts made of precious resources and heavily decorated can easily be worth thrice the value of the rest of your fortress in the early years.

Other infos from the [Bookkeeper page](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Bookkeeper):

> The desired level of accuracy [for the bookkeeper] can be set in the settings menu from the nobles screen (when the bookkeeper is highlighted). To increase above the lowest level of accuracy, the bookkeeper needs a meager office. He must work not only to attain an accuracy level, but also to maintain it.

If you're looking for good ways to increase your fortress wealth, the same page lists some:

- Checking for promising stone layers when selecting your location.
- Searching for and using valuable metals (e.g. gold, aluminium, or platinum) early on
- Choosing proficient dwarves on embark; experienced dwarves work faster, and make higher quality goods.
- Using more valuable, but still abundant stone (e.g. obsidian or flux) for "everyday items"
- Smoothing and detailing walls
- Check item value for clues on what items are valuable and how processing boosts wealth
- Build a steel armor industry
- Encrusting/decorating objects with highly skilled craftdwarves
- Assisting dwarves in strange moods, especially leaving high value gems, giant cave spider silk, and adamantine/aluminum/platinum for decorations nearby

Comment: That's how you find the total. Do you happen to know how I can find out _what contributes to the majority_ of the wealth, in my particular fortress?

Comment: In the settings menu from the nobles screen you should be able to set the level of accuracy for the bookkeeper

Comment: Edited the answer to add informations about the accuracy of the bookkeeper.

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. I'm wondering if there's a way to find e.g. whether the largest part of my wealth comes from stone crafts or from smoothed walls.

Comment: If you set his accuracy high enough, you can get the detailed amount of every item in your fortress in the status screen

Comment: Oh, I thought the `z` screen only showed the total wealth. Sorry for being thick :) I'll try it next time I'm playing.

Comment: Don't worry, no offense taken. Thanks to Reddit, [here](http://i.imgur.com/3UBOX.jpg) you have an example of a detailed log.

Comment: Mind, those are amounts rather than value...

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way in-game to see the value of everything in your fortress. But to see any values, you will need an active bookeeper (for seeing values in stocks) and appraiser (for seeing values in trade related screens).

If you have a Trade Depot, when a foreign trader is in your fortress, you can go into the "g: Move Goods to/from Depot" in the Trade Depot building's tasks. Once in it, you can "d: sort by value". This will sort EVERY ITEM not installed by the most valuable to the least. This won't show you: a) artifacts, and b) worn/installed/constructed items (a brass axe that a woodcutter is using to chop trees will not be listed; A gold table that has been "built" will not be listed, but the same gold table in a stockpile will be). To see the EXACT value of each item, you will need to view the item's description. Containers may hold very valuable items, and you will have to view the individual items in the containers to see their exact value.

In the actual trading menu, each item's value is listed.

You can view the value of all your artifacts by using the "l" (view artifact) and viewing their basic description individually.

Of course, you can always get any item's value by looking at it individually, whether you use the "k" to look around on the game screen or navigate to it via the inventory of a dwarf or goblin.

There may be a utility to list item in your fortress and its value, but if so, I don't know its name.

Comment: Um, what about the stocks menu described in the answer above?

Comment: Stocks menu do not show you the value of the items on the stock screen. To find the value of an individual item from the stocks screen, you have to: first, expand the item in the stocks if it is a multiple item, (until you see [20] *turtle biscuits* rather than the generic "[20] prepared food"), and then you have to actually "enter" the item to get the basic information screen which lists the value and weight. This isn't quick, and the stocks screen doesn't sort by value. If you are going to walk through a list of items and look individually at them, trade depot and trade screen is best.